# invalid key hash. the key hash does not mach any stored keyhash in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio, android-facebook, android-keystore

In my application i am using facebook integration. I added the hash  key and release hash key in developer site too. but it is showing "invalid key hash. The key hash XXX does not match any stored key hash. I tried all the links in google. 
but those are not  working for me. Please any one help me.

Comment: any one tell me...when we need to use hash key and release key in android studio

Answer (score 0):

Genrate key hash using

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

and it will generate a hash key. Add this hash to your facebook app console under android settings.
[Starting guide is here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started) .

Comment: only keyhash is enough na or need to give release hash key too na

Comment: From which key your app is singed in publised version, Get key hash from that key.

Comment: in published version there was no facebook login....this version only having facebook login. i used that command and get the hash key. After that add in facebook app console under settings. but again same error i  got

Comment: In fb app console, under **status & review** there is a option for **Submit Items for Approval**, click **start subblission**

Comment: after start submission one pop up window is coming...what i need to seect in that @ankur?